# How can (if possible) show a list from window1 in a datagrid from window2?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list in a window (lets say window1), that appears in a datagrid1, and also have a button that opens another window (window2) and i need to show the same list in the datagrid2 but i don´t know how.

WPF by the way.

Comment: welcome! winforms? wpf?

Comment: oh right, is for WPF, thanks!

Comment: So why not pass the data into the opened window2 and show it?

Comment: Because window1 is a form that adds data to the list, its not preestablished.

Comment: Are you have any interact with datagrid1? Ex: Create row, Delete, Edit,....

Comment: I add data to the list, then I do an itemsource and refresh to the datagrid, it works nice, but outside that window i cannot do it to the second datagrid. Or just dont know how.

Comment: You must create a new instance for the list, and in second datagrid itemsource to that instance.

Comment: When you open the second window (Window2), you can pass the List object to it and then do what ever you want to do. Assuming you are not doing any MVVM patterns.

Comment: Share the Source (via DataContext) while re-instantiating the UI controls.